# How should I create a class with functions to be shared across multiple application services with aspnetboilerplate?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, aspnetboilerplate, aspnetzero

I have code/common functionality that needs to be re-used in multiple app services (i.e. say a simple lookup function). I am looking to create a Helper class that isn't really an API, just something for other app services or even the ui mvc controllers to consume.

I read in the aspnetboilerplate documentation we should not call an app service from another app service which I agree creates a mess.

I know we can implement a custom repository inheriting RepositoryBase within the Entity Framework project with this logic and inject that repository

I also know we can create a domain service and put the code in a manager but this is more application logic than domain logic.

What's the best practice for creating a helper class that can be constructor injected into each application service?

Answer (score 0):

You may be overthinking this.

> What's the best practice for creating a helper class that can be
> constructor injected into each application service?

1. Create a new project / assembly.
2. Add the class that you want.
3. Reference that project from the projects that wish to use the class.
4. In your composition root, register the class.
5. Inject as required.

> I read in the aspnetboilerplate documentation we should not call an
> app service from another app service which I agree creates a mess.

Agreed.  However, as you state, this is not a service as such.  It is a utility class and you're not going to be calling a web-api to access the class, you'll be calling the methods directly on the injected class.